# What, according to Catholic Church, does the name "Son of Man" signify?

Tags: catholicism, christology, names-of-god

We see Jesus referring to Himself as "Son of Man" in all four Gospels (e.g., in Matthew 8:20, 9:6, 11:19; Mark 10:45, 13:26; Luke 5:24, 6:22, 7:34; and John 1:51, 3:14, 6:27, etc.). What, according to Catholic Church, does the name "Son of Man" signify?

Comment: Are you asking 'What are the attributes of Jesus the Son of Man?' or ' What attributes of Jesus identify Him as the Son of Man?' or ' Since Jesus is the Son of Man, what can we expect of him?', or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the "[Son of Man](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36562)" entry in the Catholic dictionary by Fr. John Hardon, S.J., "Son of Man" is

> The most frequently used title of Christ in the New Testament, occurring eighty-two times and, all but once ([Acts 7:55](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=7&l=55-#x)), in the Gospels. A messianic title ([Daniel 7:2](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=32&ch=7&l=2-#x)-14), it identifies the heavenly transcendence of the Savior while stressing his humanity, in contrast with the "Son of God," which emphasizes his divinity.